# Looking for Deliatitz, Russia?

Tags: russia, historical-gazetteer, 1890s

My grandfather was born in Deliatitz, Russia in 1899.

I cannot find it on a map.

Can anyone help?

His name was Alexander Freed.

Comment: Do you have an image of how this place name was written?  If so, it may help potential answerers to consider whether any letters may have been mis-transcribed.

Comment: Please give us the date of the historical record which named your grandfather's birth place. Where did you find the information?

Comment: We need one other relative at least to really look into this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be talking about a town that is no longer in Russia, but rather was in the Russian empire at the time your ancestor's record was created. In Belarus there is a town Delyatichi (Alternate names: Delyatichi [Rus], Delatycze [Pol], Delatitch [Yid], Dzialacičy [Bel], Delyatyche, Dzjaljacicy.) - I would say with almost 100% certainty that this is the town you're looking for! This was a shtetl in the Minsk Province of Belarus.

If you're doing research on a Jewish family member then you should explore these links below:

http://www.jewishgen.org/Communities/community.php?usbgn=-1942336

http://www.iajgsjewishcemeteryproject.org/belarus/delyatichi-minsk.html

This shtetl is often lumped in with nearby Lyubcha, Belarus

Answer (score 1):

I have found such references:

[Géographie universelle, Vol 3](https://books.google.ru/books?id=q_xWAAAAcAAJ&dq=Dolatitche&hl=ru&pg=RA1-PA274#v=onepage&q=Dolatitche&f=false)

Wzielub (Vsieloub) & Dolatycze (Dolatitche) petites villes

I believe that this is the same with https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delatycze

It is now territory of Belarus.